# Why does this script don't work in external js file?

Tags: javascript, html

When I put this code in HTML file, my slideshow works, but when I put it in an external js file, the slideshow doesn't work. why?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KtOK.jpg 
............................................................

full code html: https://pastebin.com/YiZhpYzk
javascript file: https://pastebin.com/11BNhL7G

```
var myIndex = 0;    
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    

    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 1300); 
}
```

Comment: Pictures of code are not helpful.  Please add any relevant code directly to your quesiton.

Comment: How are you referencing the script file in the HTML file? Do you miss `<script src="myscript.js"></script>` by chance?

Comment: I have this in my project <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>

Comment: javascript file works, but not like i would add this script in html file

Comment: place the external javascript file at the bottom of the body section of the HTML file instead head section.

Comment: it doesn't work..

Comment: hey man, like @DularaMalindu spoke, you have put the import JS in final of your code. Try this:

...
   <div class="slideshow" >
     <img class="mySlides" src="slide1.jpg"  >
     <img class="mySlides" src="slide2.jpg" >
     <img class="mySlides" src="slide3.jpg" alt="poza" >
   </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>

</body>
...

Your code is work pefectly, but is being called before the your html code is bind.

Comment: Indeed @MarcusVinnicius, at the time he calls the function the DOM is not loaded. otherwise, he has to execute the function after the document completes it's loading.

Comment: that's it, thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Try placing the entry point of the link to your js document which includes the function in different places like just before the the  tag and make sure the link to your css is correct.

Comment: if in js document I write alert("asdasd") it works so it's not this...

Comment: Are you trying to make it work on your own computer or in the cloud? Either way tru using an absolute url